# How to close the C++ interface session when Apache IoTDB suddenly shutdown?

Tags: session, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I want to ask about the C++ interface in Version 0.13 of Apache IoTDB. The IoTDB server was suddenly shut down and the C++ interface of client, `spSession->close()` has been blocked. If I tried to force the interface to close by using `std::shared_ptr<Session> m_spSession.reset()`, the interface will crash. After the server is restarted, the session can be reconnected. If the IoTDB server suddenly shuts down, how can my client close the session?